# Spinner issue, Android

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner

I am working on an Android app. A part of my UI has a spinner. The spinner has names of five places listed. Also, on the same layout, there are two radio buttons. I want to create a new activity depending on the option selected-- one from the places list and either of the two radio buttons. Suppose, place1 is selected from the list and radiobutton1 is selected, it needs to open a new intent accordingly. 
I have incorporated Adapter View in my code but the application closes after the second screen. LogCat (I'm using Eclipse) points to an adapter related issue. Here is the code. Please suggest another alternative or any modification. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.travel;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Mumbai extends Activity {
TextView tv;
//int result_code=1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.three);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Toast.makeText(this, "third Screen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    int for_spinner=0;
    int for_radio=0;
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(Mumbai.this,two.class);
            setResult(3,i);
            finish();


        }
    });


    RadioGroup radiogroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    int checkedRadioButton=radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    switch(checkedRadioButton) {
        case R.id.radio0 :  for_radio=1;
                            break;
        case R.id.radio1 :  for_radio=2;
                            break;

    }

    Spinner answer=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    answer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            int value_spinner= (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            switch(position) {
            case 0: //place1
                    int for_spinner=1;
                    break;
            case 1: //place2
                    for_spinner=2;
                    break;
            case 2: //place3
                    for_spinner=3;
                    break;
            case 3: //place4
                    for_spinner=4;
                    break;
            case 4: //place5
                    for_spinner=5;
                    break;

            }

        } 

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            int for_spinner=1;
        }

    });
    final int new_for_spinner=0;
    final int new_for_radio=0;
    for_spinner=new_for_spinner; 

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(new_for_radio==1 && new_for_spinner==1)
            {
                Intent i1= new Intent(Mumbai.this,food.class);
                startActivityForResult(i1,1);
                i1.putExtra("new_for_spinner","value");
            }
            if(new_for_radio==1 && new_for_spinner==2)
            {
                Intent i1= new Intent(Mumbai.this,food.class);
                startActivityForResult(i1,1);
                i1.putExtra("new_for_spinner","value");
            }
            if(new_for_radio==1 && new_for_spinner==3)
            {
                Intent i1= new Intent(Mumbai.this,food.class);
                startActivityForResult(i1,1);
                i1.putExtra("new_for_spinner","value");
            }
            if(new_for_radio==1 && new_for_spinner==4)
            {
                Intent i1= new Intent(Mumbai.this,food.class);
                startActivityForResult(i1,1);
                i1.putExtra("new_for_spinner","value");
            }
            if(new_for_radio==1 && new_for_spinner==5)
            {
                Intent i1= new Intent(Mumbai.this,food.class);
                startActivityForResult(i1,1);
                i1.putExtra("new_for_spinner","value");
            }



        }
    });
}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Back from Image page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You variable **new_for_spinner**, **new_for_radio** and **for_spinner** because of this line:

```
 for_spinner=new_for_spinner;
```

Also i would suggest you to read http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm because naming a class **two.class** is really bad ....

Comment: Please elaborate, I didn't quite get that. 
Also, I totally agree with changing the name. It's a trial code and it points to my second screen. Will change it. Thanks.